# How to turn on the "C++0X" experimental standard when compiling .cpp files in Android-ndk (r7)?

Tags: c++, android-ndk

When examining the "android-ndk-linux_x86/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/memory" header file, I find that this header includes other STL header files according to the

```
__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__
```

flag. I think this flag relates to the "C++0X" standard and this standard may be yet experimental in Android-ndk r7. However, I want to turn on this C++ standard in my project. (I am not sure whether this "C++0X" standard has been turned on by default)

I want to know that how should I tell Android-ndk to set this flag when I compile the .cpp files in the "project/jni" directory of an Android project. Or how could I turn on the experimental "C++0X" standard in my application.

Do I need to specify the flag using, e.g. LOCAL_CPPFLAGS and/or APP_CPPFLAGS, in the "Android.mk"/"Application.mk" file. (I am using "APP_STL := gnustl_static" in my "Application.mk")

Thanks for any suggestion.

Lawrence Tsang

Comment: C++03 standard is in existence sine 2003 probably you mean c++11 standard.

Comment: @Als According to bdonlan, I mean "C++0X" standard. I have changed my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++03 is not an experimental standard; it is the default.

C++0X, however, is an experimental standard. Its official name has now been set as C++11, but the implementation is incomplete in GCC (and everywhere else). You can enable it by passing `--std=c++0x` to GCC. Remember to check the [feature status page](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) before complaining that something is broken.

Comment: '**You can enable it by passing --std=c++0x to GCC**' But how could I pass '**--std=c++0x**' to the compiler in an Android-ndk environment. I am using "ndk-build" and am expecting to specify compile options through the "Android.mk"/"Application.mk" files.

Comment: Adding "LOCAL_CPPFLAGS = -std=c++0x" to "Android.mk" works. Thanks.